# Having a subview inside Unity for native IOS apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, openurl, deeplink

For my iOS app built with unity engine, I have a use case where I would want to direct the user to settings page from within the app itself. I am using objectiveC to create a custom plugin for iOS that directs user to settings page. But it backgrounds the app and brings up the settings page. I would like to be able to achieve this from within the app itself if its possible to show settings in some kind of subview popup in the app? I have seen this somewhere for example where the app brings up a mail subview or a google map subview inside the app itself but not sure if its possible for doing something similar with iOS native settings page?

Currently i am using openURL to simply direct user to settings URL page but I would like this to be embedded in some subview from within the app itself

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID"];     
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to show a portion of the Settings app in your own app like you can do with mail or maps. However, you can build your own UI within your app to edit settings.

Comment: Thanks ya. I figured. Having to change settings within my own app UI is desirable